# Terminology: What features must a language have for it to be considered a dynamically typed language?

Tags: terminology

What features must a language have for it to be considered a dynamically typed language

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_typing#Dynamic_typing

Answer (score 3):

Values have types, but variables do not.